# Friend functions and static data members

Tags: c++, friend

How is unqualified name lookup being performed for names using within the friend's function body? Let's consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo();

class A
{
    friend void foo(){ std::cout << a << std::endl; }
    static int a;
};

int A::a = 10;

int main(){ foo(); }
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b971d65efc00821)

The Standard states in the `N4296::7.3.1.2/3 [namespace.memdef]`:

> If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares a class,
>   function, class template or function template the friend is a member
>   of the innermost enclosing namespace.

So, I expected unqualified name lookup didn't find `A::a`, but it did. I deliberately put the `A::a` declaration after the friend's function definition in hope it wouldn't be found. What's the actual rule for the friend's unqualified name lookup?

Comment: Neat question; I'm *assuming* it has to do with the fact it's a friend, so it's able to access in-scope members of `A` while still be placed in the direct parent's scope. I've never considered this before; interesting find.

Comment: There is no relationship between the `friend` declaration and the `static` member variable. I don't know why you think they are related.

Comment: @RSahu I just asked about unqualified name lookup for stattic data members beacuse We can't use  non-ststaic members within friends' function bod directly.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv, I understand your question now. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @RSahu Since you undersntand my question, maybe you probaly know an answer?

Comment: I think that example doesn't apply to the given text. The text says "if ... first declares", but `foo()` is already declared before that. That still doesn't make me any less puzzled as to why the compiler finds the name. Which compiler, btw?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt This example was compiled with g++ (version 4.9.1 as far as I remember). Yes, I completely agree with your remark, but actually it won't change anything if I put the declaration of foo in the global namespace after the class definition. [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0319d9b3636316eb) is an example

Comment: Thank you Dmitry. Actually, I asked that before reading your answer below, otherwise I would have been a bit less puzzled, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was quite simple:

`N4296::3.4.1/8 [basic.lookup.unqual]` :

> For the members of a class X, a name ***used in a member function
>   body***, in a default argument, in an exceptionspecification, in the
>   brace-or-equal-initializer of a non-static data member (9.2), or in
>   the definition of a class member outside of the definition of X,
>   following the member’s declarator-id31, shall be declared in one of
>   the following ways:
>
> [...]
>
> (8.2) — shall be a member of class X or be a member of a base class of
>   X (10.2),
>
> [...]

`N4296::3.4.1/9 [basic.lookup.unqual]` :

> Name lookup for a name used in the definition of a ***friend function***
>   (11.3) ***defined inline*** in the class granting friendship shall proceed
>   as described for ***lookup in member function definitions***.

That's it.

UPD:

***Inlining*** is important here. That's why the friend function defined outside the class defintion cannot use static members of the class directly. For instance, the following code pritns compile-time error:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    static int a;
    friend void foo();
};

int A::a = 10;

void foo(){ std::cout << a << std::endl; }



int main(){ foo(); }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2229b5698e968fbb)**

Comment: I'm happy that you found the answer. :)