# Not able to Instantiate class inside friend function? I am getting not declared in scope error

Tags: c++, friend

I am not able to instantiate test class inside the friend function, the compiler throwing error ptr not declared in this scope. I believe friend functions have access to all the private and public members of the class yet I am getting this error. I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class test;
test* friendOfTest();

class test{
private: 
    static test* ptr;
public:
    friend test* friendOfTest();
    void someMethod(){ cout<<"someMethod()\n";}
};

test* test::ptr=NULL;

test* friendofTest(){
    ptr = new test; //Error,ptr not declared in this scope in this line
    return ptr;
}


int main(){
    test* t;
    t = friendofTest();
    t->someMethod();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `test::ptr = new test;`

Comment: `test::ptr = new test;`

Comment: 8 seconds too late >_< I'm voting to close the question as not usefull to others.

Comment: `return test::ptr;`

Comment: @YSC I agree, voting not useful

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have access to ptr, but your **syntax** is wrong:

```
test* friendofTest(){
    test::ptr = new test; // note test::
    return test::ptr;
}
```

A friend function will **not behave as a member function** to your class, it just allows it's members to be accessed even though declared private or protected.

`friendofTest` in this case will still be a completely **separate** function from your class, but you can access it's static `test` member through a **scope resolution operator** as usual, even though it's declared private.

Comment: I tried to access ptr using scope resolution like you said but I am still getting this strange error.                                                                               In function ‘test* friendofTest()’
error: ‘test* test::ptr’ is private
 test* test::ptr=NULL;
       ^
error: within this context
 test::ptr = new test;

Comment: @SadikKhan Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574616/friend-functions-and-static-data-members) question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities to make the program to compile.

The first one as the friend function is defined outside the class is to use qualified names of the static class data members. For example

```
test* friendOfTest(){
    test::ptr = new test; //Error,ptr not declared in this scope in this line
    return test::ptr;
}
```

The second one is to define the function inside the class. In this case it will be in the scope of the class.

According to the C++ Standard (11.3 Friends)

> 7 Such a function is implicitly inline. A friend function deﬁned in a
>   class is in the (lexical) scope of the class in which it is deﬁned. A
>   friend function deﬁned outside the class is not (3.4.1).

For example

```
class test{
private: 
    static test* ptr;
public:
    friend test* friendOfTest();

friend test* friendOfTest(){
    ptr = new test; //Error,ptr not declared in this scope in this line
    return ptr;
}

    void someMethod(){ cout<<"someMethod()\n";}
};
```

Here are demonstrative programs

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class test;
test* friendOfTest();

class test{
private: 
    static test* ptr;
public:
    friend test* friendOfTest();
/*
friend test* friendOfTest(){
    ptr = new test; //Error,ptr not declared in this scope in this line
    return ptr;
}
*/
    void someMethod(){ cout<<"someMethod()\n";}
};

test* test::ptr=NULL;

test* friendOfTest(){
    test::ptr = new test; //Error,ptr not declared in this scope in this line
    return test::ptr;
}


test* friendofTest();

int main(){
    test* t;
    t = friendOfTest();
    t->someMethod();
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class test;
test* friendOfTest();

class test{
private: 
    static test* ptr;
public:
//    friend test* friendOfTest();

friend test* friendOfTest(){
    ptr = new test; //Error,ptr not declared in this scope in this line
    return ptr;
}

    void someMethod(){ cout<<"someMethod()\n";}
};

test* test::ptr=NULL;
/*
test* friendOfTest(){
    test::ptr = new test; //Error,ptr not declared in this scope in this line
    return test::ptr;
}
*/

test* friendofTest();

int main(){
    test* t;
    t = friendOfTest();
    t->someMethod();
    return 0;
}
```

the both programs compile successfully.

Comment: I tried both the approach but I am still getting ptr was not declared in this scope.

Comment: @Sadik Khan See my updated post where there are shown two demonstrative programs that compile successfully.

Comment: @Sadik Khan You forgot in the second approach to use the qualified name return test::ptr;

Comment: I have tried to compile exactly in above two approaches but it seems it's still not working

Comment: @SadikKhan Copy and paste the code and try at www.ideone.com and you will see that the code compiles.